# Asp.Net SignalR Not working on load balancer with 2 instances (AWS ELB)

Tags: amazon-web-services, signalr, signalr-hub, amazon-elb

I have a SignalR application for real time support. This is hosted on AWS.
It works fine, if environment has a load balancer with single instance.

If increase instances to 2 under load balancer, SignlarR starts behaving intermittent. Broadcast few messages, lets says 4 out of 10 gets communicated over the subscribers.

- Session stickiness - 1 day
- Timeout - 10 min.
- Machine key set as same on - API, Customers App, Admin support App ( API has Hub, Admin support and Customer are the clients).

Have anyone have similar case study and how to overcome that?

Comment: Did you add a backplane?

Comment: Tried with Redis backplane. But couldn't able to acheive as getting this error message, when trying to create object of connectionmultiplexer.
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.